# (For c-FastICA) On covariance and pseudocovariance matrix of a complex random vector

Tags: ica, complex-random-variable

I am currently studying complex FastICA and the [paper](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahyvarin/papers/IJNS00.pdf) says that

> Suppose $\mathbf{s}$ is a $n\times1$ complex random vector. If $\mathbf{s}$ has zero mean, unit variance, and uncorrelated real and imaginary part of equal variances, then $E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H]=\mathbf{I}_n$ and $E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T]=\mathbf{0}_n$.

I don't quite get how $E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H]=\mathbf{I}_n$ and $E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T]=\mathbf{0}_n$ come about from the conditions.

We have the covariance matrix as
\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}(\mathbf{s}) 
&= E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H]-E[\mathbf{s}]E[\mathbf{s}^H] \\
&= E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H]-\mathbf{0}_{n\times1}\mathbf{0}_{1\times n}\\
&= E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H]\\
\end{align}
and the pseudocovariance
\begin{align}
\operatorname{pcov}(\mathbf{s}) 
&= E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T]-E[\mathbf{s}]E[\mathbf{s}^T] \\
&= E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T]-\mathbf{0}_{n\times1}\mathbf{0}_{1\times n}\\
&= E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T]\\
\end{align}
I don't quite get how to equate the last line of covariance matrix to identity and the pseucovariance to zero.

If I were to write out the matrix,
\begin{align}
E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H]
&=E\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
s_1s_1^* & s_1s_2^* &\cdots & s_1s_n^*\\
s_2s_1^* & s_2s_2^* &\cdots & s_2s_n^*\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\
s_ns_1^* & s_ns_2^* &\cdots & s_ns_n^*\\
\end{bmatrix}\right\}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T]
&=E\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
s_1s_1 & s_1s_2 &\cdots & s_1s_n\\
s_2s_1 & s_2s_2 &\cdots & s_2s_n\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\
s_ns_1 & s_ns_2 &\cdots & s_ns_n\\
\end{bmatrix}\right\}
\end{align}
I still can't quite figure how all of these eventually becomes identity and zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$E[s_ks_k^*]=E[|s_k|^2]=1$$

because the complex random variables $s_k$ have zero mean and unit variance. That means that all elements of the main diagonal of $E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H]$ equal $1$. Furthermore, with $s_k=x_k+jy_k$we have

$$\begin{align}E[s_ks^*_l]&=E[x_kx_l+y_ky_l+j(x_ly_k-x_ky_l)]\\&=E[x_kx_l]+E[y_ky_l]+jE[x_ly_k]-jE[x_ky_l]\\&=0,\qquad k\neq l\end{align}$$

because real and imaginary parts are uncorrelated. Consequently, all off-diagonal elements of $E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H]$ are zero.

The off-diagonal elements of $E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T]$ are zero for the same reason. (There's just a sign difference in the sum of the expectations, but since each of them is zero the result is the same). The main diagonal elements are

$$\begin{align}E[s_k^2]&=E[x_k^2-y_k^2+2jx_ky_k]\\&=E[x_k^2]-E[y_k^2]+2jE[x_ky_k]\\&=0\end{align}$$

because real and imaginary parts are uncorrelated, and they have equal variance, i.e., $E[x_k^2]=E[y_k^2]$.